# Is $Fx = Fcosθ$ or $Fx = Fsinθ$?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors

Sorry for the stupid question, but I've learned that Fx = Fsinθ. But then I've seen in the internet some websites saying that it was actually Fx = Fsinθ, and others saying it was Fx = Fcosθ. What formula exactly I have to use?

Ps.: θ is the angle between a tilted plane and the floor

Comment: It could be everything you want, if you don't tell us what is what

Comment: Are there situations there are Fx = Fsenθ and others there are Fx = Fcosθ? @basics

Comment: Add a sketch to your question, including the set of coordinates you're using, and your definition of $\theta$. Once, you have chosen the set of coordinates (Cartesian coordinates I guess), have drawn your vector F, and have provided the definition of $\theta$, everything should be clear

Comment: Did it. It is senθ? @basics

Comment: I've learned that $x$ stands for Alice's age but I've also learned that $x$ stands for the width of a river.  Which is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both formulas may be correct.
It depends on how you define the angle $\theta$.

It is $F_x=F\cos\theta$, if $\theta$ is defined like this:
[image]

And it is $F_x=F\sin\theta$, if $\theta$ is defined like this:
[image]

Comment: And if F is the adjacent leg and Fx the hypotenuse?

Comment: @ArturCarneiroBarroso are you just having trouble with the definitions of sine and cosine? If not just start from their definitions in terms of the side opposite $\theta$ and the adjacent side to $\theta$ in relation to the hypotenuse.

Comment: @ArturCarneiroBarroso Use the [definitions of sine and cosine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_and_cosine#Definitions).
Then you should be able to answer this by yourself.

Comment: I know what it is, and I've found how to do what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The $x$ component of a force $F$ is
$$
  F_x = F \cos\theta
$$
where $\theta$ is the angle between $F$ and the $x$ axis. You need to make sure you now which angle is used in the formula because trigonometry allows you to write the cosine of one angle as the sine of another.